# What, if anything, do you need to add to a dependent type system to get a module system?

Tags: types, module, ocaml, sml

Dependent type systems seem to support some of the uses of a ML module system. What do you get out of a module system that you do not get out of dependent records?

module ~ record

signature ~ record type

functor ~ function on records

module with an abstract type component ~ dependent record with a type field

I'm interested in how well this works as a module system, and if and how you could integrate features such as applicative functors and mixins.

Comment: I think this is common translation. I cannot recall sources for specific examples and edge cases -- if any.

Comment: Most dependent type systems do not support subtyping, so that is something that you would need to add.

Comment: are you sure that you're not confusing existential types with dependent types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few disclaimers:

- Different languages in the ML family have somewhat different implementations of the module system. For that matter, different implementations of the *same* language have differences. In this answer, I'll focus exclusively on Standard ML as specified in *The Definition of Standard ML (Revised)*.
- Likewise, different dependently-typed languages have different features.
- I'm not as knowledgeable about dependent types as I could be. I think I understand them enough for purposes of this answer, but of course, we don't always know what we don't know. :-)
- This sort of question is more subjective than it might seem, because it's not always obvious what actually counts as a thing that you "get".

  - For an example of what I mean: Standard ML defines `fun ...` by showing how to transform it to `val rec ...`. So you could easily argue that the 'fun' syntax doesn't "get" you anything, since anything you can write with the 'fun' syntax is something you can easily write with the 'val rec' syntax; but apparently the language designers felt that it *does* get you something — clarity, convenience, cleanness, whatever — because otherwise they wouldn't have bothered to define this form that they clearly understood was equivalent.
  - This is especially true for the module system. Many of the features of Standard ML modules are actually achievable with just the Standard ML "core" — no need for dependent types, even — except that modules provide a much pleasanter syntax and encourage modular design. Even functors, which you compare to functions on records, aren't quite like regular functions, in that you can't "call" them inside an expression, so they can't appear in loops or conditions, they can't call themselves recursively (which is just as well since the recursion would necessarily be infinite), and so on. Is this a limitation of functors, potentially fixable by a more general approach? Or would a more general approach make it less pleasant to use functors the way they're intended? I think a case can be made either way.

  So, I'll just call out a few features that make Standard ML modules good at their job, and that aren't, to my limited knowledge, provided by current dependently-typed languages (and that even if they were, wouldn't be inherent consequences of having dependent types). You can judge for yourself which ones, if any, really "count".

---

**value constructors**

A structure can contain not just types and values, but also value *constructors*, which can be used in pattern matching. For example, you can write things like this:

```
fun map f List.nil = List.nil
  | map f List.cons (h, t) = List.cons (f h, map f t)
```

where a pattern uses a value constructor from a structure. I don't think there's an essential reason that a dependent type system *couldn't* support this, but it seems awkward.

Likewise, structures can contain exceptions, which, same story.

---

**'open' declarations**

An `open` declaration copies the entirety of a structure — all the values, types, nested structures, etc. — into the current environment, which can be either the top-level environment or a smaller scope (such as `local` or `let`).

One use of this is to define a structure that *enriches* another structure (or even the "same" structure, in that the new one can have the same name and thereby shadow the old binding). For example, if I write:

```
structure List = struct
  open List

  fun map f nil = nil
    | map f cons (h, t) = cons (f h, map f t)
end
```

then List now has all of the bindings it had before, plus a new List.map (which may replace a previously-defined List.map). (Likewise, I can use an `include` specification to augment a signature, though for that one I probably would *not* reuse the same name.)

Of course, even without this feature, you could also write a series of declarations like `datatype list = datatype List.list`, `val hd = List.hd`, etc., to copy everything out of a structure; but I think you'll agree that `open List` is much clearer, less error-prone, and more robust in the face of future changes.

There are languages that have this sort of operation for records — for example, JavaScript's spread/rest syntax, starting in ECMAScript 2018, lets you copy all fields from an existing object to a new one, adding or replacing as desired — but I'm not sure if any dependently-typed languages have it.

---

**flexible matching**

In Standard ML, a structure matches a signature even if it has extra bindings not specified by the signature, or if it has bindings that are more polymorphic than what is specified by the signature, or the like.

This means that a functor can require only what it actually needs, and still be used with structures that also have other things the functor doesn't care about. (This is in contrast to regular functions; `val first = # 1` only cares about the first element of a tuple, but its type has to specify exactly how many elements are in the tuple.)

In a dependently-typed language, this would amount to a kind of subtype relation. I don't know if any dependently-typed languages have it — it wouldn't surprise me — but certainly some don't.

---

**projection and abstraction**

Continuing on the previous point: when you match a structure to a signature, the result is (if I may simplify a bit) the "projection" of the structure onto the subspace specified by the signature, that is, the structure "minus" whatever is not specified by the signature.

This effectively "hides" aspects of the structure, analogously to how you might use 'private' in a language like C++ or Java.

You can even have 'friends' (in the C++ sense) by initially defining the structure more openly, and then rebinding the same structure identifier more narrowly:

```
structure Foo = struct
  ...
end

... code with unfettered access to the contents of Foo ...

structure Foo = Foo :> FOO

... code with access only to what's specified by FOO ...
```

Because you can define a signature very precisely, you have a high degree of granularity here in what you expose and how. The grammar lets you refine a signature on-the-fly (for example, `FOO where type foo = int` is a valid signature expression), and because it's often desired to retain *all* types without making them abstract, there's a simple syntax for that (for example, `Foo : FOO` is roughly equivalent to `Foo :> FOO where type foo = Foo.foo and type bar = Foo.bar and ...`).

In a dependently-typed language that supported flexible matching via subtyping (above), some of this would probably come together with that; but I list it separately, and call out the syntactic conveniences, in order to highlight how Standard ML modules serve their intended purposes.

---

Well, that's probably enough examples to show the idea. If you don't feel that any of the above really "count", then listing more features probably wouldn't change that. :-)

Comment: "Flexible matching" can be considered a specific form of "projection and abstraction", so this is just a single point, not two. In my view, there are more subtle points than what you've suggested, since I think that all of your features can be expressed in a dependently typed language with enough record functionality.

A more important aspect is linkage. With plain records, you are forced to bind most specific record-modules first, which contradicts the common intuition. E.g., record `Point` must come before `Rectangle` if the latter uses the former, but the opposite direction is clearer.

Comment: Thus, there should be some way to assemble a complete program out of a sequence of intertwined modules, possibly split through multiple files. Records simply are not about that.

Another thing to consider is abstract type components. Dependent pairs where the first component is a type are not equivalent to existential types, because the type component is not really hidden. Thus, records lack a way to differentiate between concrete and abstract type components of a module. Using the representation of a (morally) hidden type is an encapsulation problem.

Comment: @Hirrolot: Thanks for your comments! Re: whether "flexible matching" is a specific form of "projection and abstraction" that warrants being listed separately: I actually addressed that in the answer, and explained why I did list them separately. You certainly don't have to agree! But my take is that from the perspective of someone *using* ML modules, these are two related features that both help achieve the purpose of modules. Re: linkage: modules as specified in the *Definition* don't actually change that, do they? The *Definition* assumes a linear order of declarations. *[continued]*

Comment: @Hirrolot: That said, it's certainly no coincidence that the *Definition*'s approach is compatible with implementations having more sophisticated approaches for autoloading modules as needed, letting them be defined in separate files, etc. Re: "abstract component types": You may well be right. The OP wrote "module with an abstract type component ~ dependent record with a type field", but I'm not 100% clear on the connection. I don't remember if it made sense to me back when I wrote this answer, or if I just accepted it and plowed ahead. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I understand that your initial answer deals with the definition of SML. When I suggested that modules should be ordered "most general to most specific", I meant that in principle -- i.e., I consider the SML module system approach ineffective in this regard. But as far as SML is concerned only, sophisticated linkage should not be a problem for dependent records as well. On the other hand, it'll anyway make sense to separate modules through files -- as ATTAPL says, "modules arise even if we try to avoid them!"

Comment: Update: I'm glad to see that Cayenne seems to allow mixed `concrete`/`abstract` components in a single record type. So what remains to be done for dependent records to scale them to a full-blown module system is linkage (although it can be implemented as a tiny layer on top of records).